# How to write php excel code in phpexcel format and print dynamic label?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader, phpexcel-1.8.0

I have a dynamic cell coming from a database. How can I print it into Phpexcel format?

```
$out_table = '';
$k=0;
    mysql_data_seek($query_result1,0);
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query_result1,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $out_table .= "<th valign=\"top\">".$labels[$k]." (value1)</th>";
            $out_table .= "<th valign=\"top\">".$labels[$k]." (value2)</th>";
            $k++;   
    }

    echo $out_table;
    //print_r($out_table);die;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to use [PHPSPREEDSHEET](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the evolution of PHPEXCEL, here's an example:

```
require 'DB.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx as xlsx; // Instead PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing as drawing; // Instead PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory as io_factory; // Instead PHPExcel_IOFactory


$query = 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ?';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$objPHPExcel    =   new Spreadsheet();


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//NAME WORKSHEET
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Test");


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setOrientation(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPaperSize(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A12', 'ROW1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B12', 'ROW2');

$rowCount   =   1;

}
while($row  =   $result->fetch_assoc()){


      //BORDER  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);


      //VALUE
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['row1']);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['row2']);


    $rowCount++; //ADD COUNT 
}

$objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=EXAMPLE.xlsx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much i got although i have a different approach for this ` $out_table = '';
    $k = 0;
    mysql_data_seek($query_result1, 0);
    $col = 35;
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, trim($labels[$k] . " (value1)", ','));
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col + 1, 1, trim($labels[$k] . " (value2)", ','));
        $col = $col + 2;
        $k++;
    }

    echo $out_table;`

Comment: If you want i can post output method

Comment: I am facing with another issue please check my question as i am posting it

Comment: any idea about this?  if ($temp[0] == $labels[$i]) {
                    $name = explode(">", $dd1[$j]);
                    $inn_table .= '<td>' . $name[1] . '</td>';
                    
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }